# Can't create composite primary key with foreign key in PLAY 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

This is a situation I want to represent in my PLAY project:

```
table clients {
     client_id (pk),
     description
}

table items {
     client_id (fk, pk),
     item_id (pk)
}
```

In the 'items' table I want to have a composite primary key that will consist of combined client_id and item_id. I have read JPA documentation as well as many posts on the topic but everything fails again and again. This is one of many versions I have tried - closest to the JPA documentation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items extends Model {
    ItemsPK primaryKey;

    public Items() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public ItemsPK getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }

    public void setPrimaryKey(ItemsPK pk) {
        primaryKey = pk;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class ItemsPK implements Serializable {
    private long itemId;
    private Client client;

    public ItemsPK() {
    }

    @Column(name = "item_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(long itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    //public int hashCode() {...
    //public boolean equals(Object obj) {...
}
```

The above code (as well as many other different setups) produce following error during play launch:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for
>   models.ItemsPK
>           at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:73)
>   ~[ebean.jar:na]
>           at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1100)
>   ~[ebean.jar:na]

I don't have a clue what might be wrong with my code. I'm starting to think that it is a PLAY bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a solid reason to insist on composite PK? Even if you manage to handle this one, you may face several other problems because of this. Why not add an additional column (say items_id) to items table and put a unique index on (client_id, item_id). (I suppose item_id refers to item table just as client_id refers to clients table).

Comment: @bpgergo Thank You for Your answer. Your solution is acceptable, but I would rather avoid additional column and index. It surprises me that such a simple case needs to be worked around. If no resolution will appear in a few days I'll reconsider. As for the item_id, currently it is not referencing any other tables, but that might change in the future.

Comment: tags: hibernate** are incorrect here. there is no Hibernate nor JPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cześć,

This not an answer, rather suggestion. Can you tell me what is main goal of using composite PK in your case? Your both models would be reaaaaly small and easy with Ebean ORM

models/Client.java

```
package models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Client extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String description;
}
```

models/Item.java

```
package models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Item extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Client client;
}
```

and that's all. It gives you what you need except the composite PK

Comment: In this system each item_id should be unique only within one client_id. In other words two different clients can have items with the same id, but a single client cannot have two identical item_ids. Item_id is a user-defined value. Each user can have it's own set of items. In that regard Your answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Yhm, just common @ManyToMany relation, of course Ebean will create `ItemClient` table for this + you've to ensure that relation doesn't exist before saving new one, however I'm still thinking that's easier and cheaper solution. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you are not able to use GeneratedValue inside an EmbeddedId, the values in a composite key must be assigned. See excerpt below.

> The use of the GeneratedValue annotation is only required to be
>   supported for simple primary keys. Use of the GeneratedValue
>   annotation is not supported for derived primary keys.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/GeneratedValue

I would recommend not using a composite key for this as `itemId` would be sufficient in generating a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't disabled Ebean. Ebean is the default ORM for Play 2. If you want to use JPA you have to disable Ebean.

So in your Build.scala, add this:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    ebeanEnabled := false
)
```

And in your application.conf edit this line:

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

Comment: You can use ebean with JPA annotations, so no reason to disable ebean.