# How do I represent a join table with an extra field using eBean and Kotlin?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, kotlin, ebean

I'm adding a field "role" to the book_author table from the canonical author/book many-to-many relationship example:

```
create table author (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  name                          varchar(255),
  constraint pk_author primary key (id)
);

create table book (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  title                         varchar(255),
  constraint pk_book primary key (id)
);

create table book_author (
  book_id                       bigint not null,
  author_id                     bigint not null,
  role                          varchar(255),
  constraint pk_book_author primary key (book_id,author_id)
);
```

I can only get eBean to play nicely with this if I add a surrogate primary key (`id bigint auto_increment not null`) to the `book_author` table.  But I don't want to do that because:

- The combination of `book_id` and `author_id` need to be ***unique***
- The table needs to be ***indexed*** on `book_id` and `author_id`
- Surrogate keys make sense as immutable unique identifiers.  In this case, the composite natural key performs the same role - If the book or author with an ID matching a record in book_author is deleted, then the book_author record should be deleted too (on delete cascade).

In short, this is what a composite primary key is intended for.  In fact, if there's no `role` field on `book_author`, [eBean correctly generates the table without me making any corresponding Kotlin/Java class](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/One-off_Examples/wiki/2017.03.21-eBean-Kotlin-simplest-ManyToMany-association).

Here's my best attempt at the Kotlin code (I think Java would have the same issue):

```
// Puts an ID field (surrogate key) on tables that extend this.
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseModel {
    @Id var id:Long = 0
}

@Entity
class Author(@Column var name: String): BaseModel() {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    val books:MutableList<Book> = mutableListOf()
}

@Entity
class Book(@Column var title:String) : BaseModel() {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book") // mapped in both directions!
    val authors:MutableList<Author> = mutableListOf()
}

// BREAKS: missing the primary key.
// BREAKS: book.getBookAuthors() always returns zero
// DOESNT INITIALIZE PROPERLY: ebean.find(BookAuthor.class)
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = arrayOf(UniqueConstraint(columnNames = arrayOf("book_id", "author_id"))))
class BookAuthor(@ManyToOne @Key val book:Book,
                 @ManyToOne @Key val author:Author) {
    @Column var role:String = ""
}
```

Here's what book_author looks like in db-create-all.sql:

```
create table book_author (
  role                          varchar(255),
  book_id                       bigint,
  author_id                     bigint,
  constraint uq_book_author_author_id_book_id unique (author_id,book_id)
);

alter table book_author_assoc add constraint fk_book_author_assoc_book_id foreign key (book_id) references book (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_book_author_assoc_book_id on book_author_assoc (book_id);

alter table book_author_assoc add constraint fk_book_author_assoc_author_id foreign key (author_id) references author (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_book_author_assoc_author_id on book_author_assoc (author_id);
```

As a work-around (for similar tables), I've just made `BookAuthor` extend `BaseModel` which adds an id field to BookAuthor.  Then everything just works.  But doing that just feels wrong somehow.

Very similar question:
[Can't create composite primary key with foreign key in PLAY 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723465/cant-create-composite-primary-key-with-foreign-key-in-play-2-0)

**Update:**

I followed a [JPA Composite Key Tutorial](http://uaihebert.com/tutorial-jpa-composite-primary-key/) and created an @Embeddable composite key class:

```
@Embeddable
class BookAuthorCompositeKey(@Column var book: Book?,
                             @Column var author: Author?) : Serializable {
    // Your class must have a no-arq constructor
   constructor() : this(null, null)

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
            (other is BookAuthorCompositeKey) &&
            (aook == other.Book) &&
            (author == other.Author)

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var ret:Int = 0
        try { ret += book!!.hashCode() } catch (ignore:NullPointerException) { }
        try { ret += author!!.hashCode() } catch (ignore:NullPointerException) { }
        return ret
    }
}
```

Then updated BookAuthor with the new class, and added cascade all to the relationships on Book and Author:

```
@Entity
class Author(@Column var name: String): BaseModel() {
    @OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL)) // CHANGED
    val books:MutableList<Book> = mutableListOf()
}

@Entity
class Book(@Column var title:String) : BaseModel() {
    @OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL)) // CHANGED
    val authors:MutableList<Author> = mutableListOf()
}

@Entity
class BookAuthor(@EmbeddedId val back:BookAuthorCompositeKey) {
    @Column var role:String = ""
}
```

But db-create-all.sql looks even worse now - it's only got a reference to one of the tables!

create table book_author (
    book_id                       bigint not null,
    role                          varchar(255)
  );

Hmm...  I'm starting to think that eBean requires a surrogate key.

Comment: // Your class must have a no-arq constructor ... Yes the JPA spec says so but with Ebean we do not need the no-arg constructor (as Ebean mandates enhancement and effectively creates a constructor method if required as part of that enhancement process).

Comment: That @Embeddable ... in Kotlin could/should be a 'data' class (as it would then automatically have the hashCode/equals implementation) but I honestly haven't tried it yet to confirm that works as expected.

Comment: Ok. Gee, deleted my previous comment about those annotations not being read ... found a bug with @Size (validation and meta annotations not being read in this scenario) ... and looking into that.  Cricky!!

Comment: @RobBygrave the JPA Composite Key "Embeddable" solution is really ugly.  Even if you ignore the annoyance of making the composite key class, you have to *use* that class everywhere you want to deal with the BookAuthor relationship.  `.where().eq("back", new BookAuthorCompositeKey(someBook, someAuthor))` and `myAuthor.getBookAuthors().contains(new BookAuthor(new BookAuthorCompositeKey(someBook, myAuthor)))`  I don't even want that functionality - I was just curious about it.

Comment: Yes agreed. We wouldn't think twice about it in sql but in the orm query the composite key is "not great" to deal with.  We have the Kotlin native query bean generation but even that would be a bit yuk.  Composite keys are also not great with L3 ElasticSearch integration.

Comment: Thanks @RobBygrave for personally responding and for eBean!    Adding a surrogate key to a join table could be a minor issue for existing databases, but it's a non-issue when you're generating the database.  And it works great in Java/Kotlin!  I was just surprised because the simple ManyToMany generates a beautiful join table with a composite key.  It just left me wondering why I couldn't get that when making a joining class with one additional field.  But I guess query bean generation, elastic search difficulties explain it.  Thanks!